# Retag suggestion reject-and-edited with only minor inclusions

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits, specific-edit

I recently made a [retag edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22579326) on a question which lacked a language tag. The result was a Reject and Edit, with the retag still in place, and just minor paragraphing and adding backticks to method names and outputs. When I asked in the comments about why it wasn't an Improve instead, the reasoning given was:

> Tag-only edit without fixing other problems. I showed you the proper way to do it, if I improve edit it you probably won't even check the edit again.

Personally, I think this was worth an Improve, and not an outright Reject and Edit. Had I have thought that these could've used backticks in the first place I would've also added these along with the retag, but I think adding these in this instance was fairly trivial in itself, and *not* having them wasn't as obvious and didn't have a negative impact on the post in the same way as incorrectly formatted code, so I glossed over it at the time. It wasn't any actual blocks of code which were missing code formatting, just expected outputs and inline method names.

Additionally, the assertion that I "won't even check the edit again" if it was an Improve instead is a bit harsh. I do make the effort to check how suggested edit reviews end up, mainly out of curiosity, but also to see how I could improve future suggestions (which is also why I'm here now!) until when/if I end up getting the proper privileges.

Am I being too pedantic, or was a Reject and Edit the right course of action in this instance?

Comment: It's funny that neither you nor the reviewer picked up on the question's title, or on _"We'll my professor gave us this problem and he wants us to do it "_.

Comment: In fairness, I think I'm a bit overdue for an eye test :)

Comment: Only because of those, I believe rejecting your tag-only edit would have been a fair call, even more coupled with possible code-formatting improvements.

Comment: @yivi  Thanks, just fixed that. Not only us, but the editor after us missed that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is my original reply to your question in the comment there:

> Tag-only edit without fixing other problems. I showed you the proper way to do it, if I improve edit it you probably won't even check the edit again. If you don't want to spend much effort to really improve posts you can leave it to others, or you can earn 2k rep first, by then your edits need not to be reviewed by others. If you have doubt about this you can ask a question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

It seems the edit link won't show the whole picture after the edit has been made.
So just to give a whole view, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55369599/1) is the original question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/ab8b23d8-b207-424f-a596-94e83e3a2bfd/view-source) is its source.
The newlines, the snippets, and sample outputs etc seems just wrong.
The result layout is not that OP wanted.

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed.

This is the reason automatically created by the system, let everyone judge if it falls into this category.

I used ***probably***, maybe it's too strong and too big a possibility, if so my apologies to you.
I didn't assume that it will surely happen, just that I think it's quite likely.

The question was posted at 04:00:35Z.
You made the tag-only edit at 04:06:04Z.
I reject and edited it at 04:39:49Z.
So there was plenty of time for you to improve your edit/suggestion before my review.

You can and it's recommended to improve your suggestion, because your suggestion will prevent other under-2k-rep users to better edit it. And a low quality improvement somehow will need more time to be approved -- because some reviewers don't like this but in order to not to offend the proposer, choose to skip instead of refuse.

I hope you won't stop improving posts, just please try to be comprehensive.
And please contribute more by other ways, once you have reached 2000 reputation, tiny improvement won't be a problem any more.
You are actually a senior member compares to me, so I hope you can understand these.